# Is it possible to run a final function vb after Postback Event?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, asynchronous, postback, master-pages

I have a system that has a gridview on one page with an Update Panel. On selection of one row of a gridview the system posts-back using that CommandName and CommandArgument to post the row that is selected, and then set a Session variable as the ID of that posted selected row. The other controls run Async correctly and the button in question is already registered using this on the RowDataBound event.

```
Dim gvRowSelect As GridViewRow = e.Row   
Dim imbSelect As ImageButton = DirectCast(gvRowSelect.FindControl("imbSelect"), ImageButton)
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(imbSelect)
```

I would like to try and get this session on the button command and somehow within the master page, set a label to the current Session. On the imbSelect command the code is:

```
Dim cellSnapshot As TableCell = gvSnapshots.Rows(e.CommandArgument).Cells(0)
Session("Snapshot") = cellSnapshot.Text
```

Within the masterpage is there anyway of calling a function after the Page_Load, and after it has resolved all Postback events?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [LoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) or [PreRenderComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.prerendercomplete.aspx) event ?

Comment: The final call for the title is within a masterpage, I didn't think LoadComplete or PreRenderComplete are methods within a masterpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your master page pre render will happen after all postback events have completed

```
     Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles Me.PreRender

     End Sub
```

Or another way would be to create a property on your master page and update it directly from your method

```
     'On your master page
     Private _myValue As String             'If you want the master page to remember this between postbacks use an asp:HiddenField instead of a string, or store it in the Session
     Public Property MyProperty() As String
        Get
            Return _myValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            _myValue = value
        End Set
     End Property

    'On your userControl or Page
    CType(Me.Master, MyMasterPage).MyProperty
```

Or another another way would be to raise a bubble event. They're handy for passing messages back up the hirarchy towards your master page

```
    RaiseBubbleEvent(Me, e)
```

Then have override you OnBubbleEvent on your master page (just google for some examples of raising and handling bubble events)

Comment: Thanks, I used a combination of the PreRender and my answer, however yours came closest to other problems that can occur.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure this out using a combination of some hidden knowledge on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

This shows how to create a reference to a masterpage, so all I had to do was create a function on the masterpage that isn't referenced anywhere else. Then when the button event is fired:

```
Dim cellSnapshot As TableCell = gvSnapshots.Rows(e.CommandArgument).Cells(0)    
Session("Snapshot") = cellSnapshot.Text    
gvSnapshots.DataBind()    
Master.PageSetTitles()
```

I.e. the PageSetTitles function gets the Session variable and sets the label within the

While including this:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Site.Master"  %>
```

In the page.